# Plotting a network graph from a symmetric matrix in R

Tags: r, igraph

I have a large 2414x2414 matrix, where the rows and columns of the matrix represent sectors within countries -- the rows and columns are symmetric, such that the order of the sectors/countries is exactly the same along rows as it is along columns.

If I have the following matrix, how do I plot the network in igraph?

```
set.seed(1)
m<-matrix(runif(2414*2414), nrow = 2414, ncol=2414)
```

Many thanks,

Khalid

Comment: How is this matrix a graph?  I _think_ that you want 2414 nodes, but when should there be a link between two nodes?  Please explain how your data is supposed to represent a graph.

Comment: You're correct -- I'd like to plot 2414 nodes, where each element of the matrix indicates the volume of trade between the corresponding nodes. Does this help?

Comment: Your example using `runif` would have non-zero entries on the diagonal,  so most nodes would be connected to themselves. Also, in all likelihood, _every_ node would be connected to every other node. Drawing a fully connected graph with 2414 nodes does not seem very useful. _Very_ hard to read.  Is it true with your real data that many entries in the matrix are zero?

Comment: Unfortunately most of the matrix elements are not equal to 0 -- I imagine I'll have to filter out small values.

Comment: Yes,    even squeezing 2414 nodes on a graph will be crowded, but 2414*2413/2 = 2912491 links will be impossible to see.